# I want to check if element exist in the table using jQuery based on if not in the first page , it will be at the last page for sure using Cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, assertion

so, I have  a worst case when I add two elements and I want to click in the first element using this case it will not work , because I check the button if it's disabled so, element will be at the first page surly .

what if the button was not disabled and the element not in the last page how I can check without any fail ?

```
  cy.get('button[ aria-label="last page"]').then(($button) => {
    if($button.is(':disabled')){
      cy.get('table').contains(`${paymentMethodsInfo.paymentMethod.name.ar} ${0} --- ${todaysDate}`)
      .should('be.visible')
      .click();
    }else{
      cy.wrap($button).click();
      cy.get('table').contains(`${paymentMethodsInfo.paymentMethod.name.ar} ${0} --- ${todaysDate}`)
      .should('be.visible')
      .click();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write conditional logic like this using https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if If you don't know what page the element is on, you can go through the pages one by one until you find it using https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse plugin